# Issue with variable nested dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In this case an example is worth a thousand words:

```
    interface IProvider {

    }

    class DefaultProvider : IProvider {
        private readonly ProviderSettings settings;

        public DefaultProvider(ProviderSettings settings) {
            this.settings = settings;
        }
    }

    class ProviderSettings {
        string Name { get; set;}
    }

    class SystemProviderSettings : ProviderSettings {
        public SystemProviderSettings() {
            this.Name = "System";
        }
    }

    class ContextualProviderSettings : ProviderSettings {
        // etc.
    }
```

Each `IProvider` implementation should take a ctor dependency on ProviderSettings, as this is what allows us to switch providers without making any changes to our application.

We wire up the default `ProviderSettings` to be `ContextualProviderSettings`. As you might guess, this set's the `Name` based on something contextual, let's say the current user's name.

However, in some cases we want to use `SystemProviderSettings`. Usually this is for a specific service:

```
    public class SomeSystemService : ISomeService {
        public SomeSystemService(IProvider provider) {
            // I need a provider scoped for the "system"
        }
    }
```

I then have a bit of a job wiring up these dependencies with my DI tool (StructureMap):

```
For<ISomeService>().Use<SomeService>()
        .Ctor<IStorageProvider>()
            .Is(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<IStorageProvider>... this feels wrong
```

So I think that this can be done in a better way. I tried the decorator pattern but I don't want to decorate a specific `IProvider` implementation. The idea would be to have a `SystemProvider` that wraps whatever has been configured as the default `IProvider`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing what a nights sleep will do.

Simple solution, use a factory:

```
public class IProviderFactory {
    IProvider Create(ProviderSettings settings);
}
```

I can create a factory for each provider implementation and pass in the relevant ProviderSettings at run time.